# Bootstrap carousel and showing multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using @paulalexandru(https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522687/paulalexandru) solution to showing multiple items on a bootstrap slider. Unfortunately I'm not advanced enough with javascript to be able to show 4 items(or more or less) instead of the current 3. Can someone break the following code down maybe so I can understand where to even begin to understand what tells the script to only show 3 at a time? 
Here's a functioning JS fiddle of Paul's work. 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/paulalexandru/at606jpe/light/

I understand the CSS just fine but I know the carousel doesn't solely rely on the CSS for displaying here. I'm trying to make it show x items based on screen size

Comment: Can't you use a simple plugin like bxSlider?

Comment: I could but I'd rather not since this carousel already works just fine, just need to change how many are shown.

Answer (score 0):

I changed all the:

- `33%` to `25%`.
- `col-md-4` to `col-md-3`

And here's the result:

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -25%;             }
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 25%;              }
.carousel-inner .next         { left: 25%               }
.carousel-inner .prev         { left: -25%              }
.carousel-control.left        { background-image: none; }
.carousel-control.right       { background-image: none; }
.carousel-inner .item         { background: white;      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/at606jpe/685/**

Comment: This isn't properly proportioned. Though you did change the column size, it is still only showing 3 at a time and leaving where the 4th would be as a gap.